# metodo delta loteria

Tags: python

Estoy haciendo un algoritmo para seleccionar los números de un sorteo de lotería mediante el método “delta” que consiste en:

1. Elige un numero bajo. Que se encuentre entre el 1 y el 5.  En este caso, vamos a coger el 3.
2. Escoge dos números entre el 1 y el 8. Nos quedamos con el 2 y el 7.
3. Ahora selecciona un número cercano al 8. El 9, por ejemplo.
4. Elige otros dos números entre el 8 y el 15. Por ejemplo el 11 y el 14
5. Mezclar los números.
6. Comprobar que la suma de tus números no sea mayor que la cantidad de números que se juegan en el sorteo escogido.
7. A partir del primer número, , el siguiente numero se escoge sumando los dos primeros de la serie. Y así hasta completar la secuencia.

Genero la combinación sin problemas pero estoy atascado en este punto:
Quiero que se genere no solo una combinación sino que generes varias y a las cuales les pueda aplicar varios filtros. por ejemplo:

1. La suma de la combinacion debe estar entre 100 y 160.. [3,12,15,34,46,49], CUMPLIRIA PORQUE LA SUMA DE TODOS SUS NUMEROS ES 159
2. Que tres sean número pares (2, 20, 38…) y tres números impares (3,15,49)
3. Que tres números sean  bajos (del 1 al 25) y tres números altos (del 25 al 49)
4. Que no haya mas de dos números seguidos,por ejemplo esta no pasaría el filtro (36, 37, 38…).
5. que como maximo haya 2 multiplos de 3, 2 multiplos 5 y 2 multimplos de t....por ejemplo esta no pasaría al haber mas de 5 multiplos de 5 (5, 10, 15, 20, 25…)
6. Repartir los números entre las diferentes decenas (1-10, 31-40, etc.).

Los filtros comiéndome un poco el coco quizás pueda sacarlos pero estoy atascado en como debería ser la estructura de control que genere las combinaciones y la implementacion de los los filtros, para finalmente obtener  10 o 12 combinaciones.
A ver quien me puede echar una mano.
Un saludo

```
import random


def seleccion_numeros():
    #random.seed()#
    for x in range(1):
        return (random.randint(1, 5))


def seleccion_numeros2():
    #random.seed(15)#
    for x in range(1):
        return (random.randint(1, 8))


def seleccion_numeros3():
    #random.seed(23)#
    for x in range(1):
        return (random.randint(1, 8))


def seleccion_numeros4():
    #random.seed(30)#
    for x in range(1):
        return (random.randint(7, 9))


def seleccion_numeros5():
    #random.seed(35)#
    for x in range(1):
        return (random.randint(8, 15))


def seleccion_numeros6():
    #random.seed(40)#
    for x in range(1):
        return (random.randint(8, 15))


suma = seleccion_numeros() + seleccion_numeros2() + seleccion_numeros3(
) + seleccion_numeros4() + seleccion_numeros5() + seleccion_numeros6()


lista = [seleccion_numeros(), seleccion_numeros2(), seleccion_numeros3(
), seleccion_numeros4(), seleccion_numeros5(), seleccion_numeros6()]


def unsort(l):
    return random.sample(l, len(l))


lista_desordenada = unsort(lista)


def calculoformula():
    return lista_desordenada[0]+lista_desordenada[1]


def calculoformula2():
    return calculoformula()+lista_desordenada[2]


def calculoformula3():
    return calculoformula2()+lista_desordenada[3]


def calculoformula4():
    return calculoformula3()+lista_desordenada[4]


def calculoformula5():
    return calculoformula4()+lista_desordenada[5]


def combi_gana():
    return [lista_desordenada[0], calculoformula(), calculoformula2(), calculoformula3(), calculoformula4(), calculoformula5()]


def suma_combi_gana():
    suma_combinacion = lista_desordenada[0] + calculoformula() + calculoformula2(
    ) + calculoformula3() + calculoformula4() + calculoformula5()
    return suma_combinacion


lista_combinacion = combi_gana()
suma_combinacion = suma_combi_gana()


print(combi_gana())  # me genera la combinacion segun el metodo delta


# ahora genero una funcion para que genera sucesivas combinacion segun el metodo descrito
def generar_multiples_combinaciones(lista):
    yield lista_combinacion




# POR ULTIMO quiero aplicar una serie de filtros para que la combinacion selecccionada cumpla las condiciones del filtro que son:

# 1º la suma de la combinacion debe estar entre 100 y 160 .....[3,12,15,34,46,49]...CUMPLIRIA PORQUE LA SUMA DE TODOS SUS NUMEROS ES 159
# 2º  QUE  tres Ssean número pares (2, 20, 38…) y tres números impares (3,15,49)
# 3º que  tres números sean  bajos (del 1 al 25) y tres números altos (del 25 al 49)
# 4º que no haya mas de dos numeros seguidos .....por ejemplo esta no pasaria el filtro (36, 37, 38…).
# 5º que como maximo haya 2 multiplos de 3, 2 multiplos 5 y 2 multimplos de t....por ejemplo esta no pasaria al haber mas de 5 multiplos de 5 (5, 10, 15, 20, 25…)
# 6º  repartir los números entre las diferentes decenas (1-10, 31-40, etc.).

for i in generar_multiples_combinaciones(lista):
    if sum(i) >= 100 and sum(i) <= 150:
        print("Generando ... su combinacion ganadora es: ", combi_gana())
        if suma_combinacion >= 100 and suma_combinacion <= 150:
            print("ok")
```

Answer (score 0):

Una forma común de manejar una cantidad variable de operaciones del mismo tipo, es definir una serie de funciones que reciban los mismos parámetros.

En este caso, se trata de validar aspectos de una lista de 6 elementos. Definimos entonces funciones que reciban una lista y retornen `True` o `False` según cumpla o no la condición.

Este es el código para las tres primeras condiciones:

```
def condicion1(lista):
    return 100 <= sum(lista) <= 150

def condicion2(lista):
    return len([x for x in lista if x % 2]) == 3

def condicion3(lista):
    ordenados = sorted(lista)
    return ordenados[2] <= 25 and ordenados[3] >= 25
```

Ventaja adicional: es fácil evaluar si las condiciones están bien escritas.

Ahora la parte importante: evaluar una lista y proceder sólo si todas las condiciones se cumplen. Python tiene una función intrinsica llamada `all`, que recibe un iterable o generador y devuelve `True` si todos los elementos también lo son. Muy cómodo:

```
for i in generar_multiples_combinaciones(lista):
    if all(cond(lista) for cond in [condicion1, condicion2, condicion3]):
            print(f"{lista} ok")
```

En este caso, `all` recibe un *generador*, no una lista. Con una lista, todas las condiciones son evaluadas primero; con un generador cada condición se va evaluando mientras la anterior sea `True`. Así se evitan evaluaciones innecesarias.

`cond` es un *objeto funcion*, por lo que `cond(lista)` es una llamada a esa función, la que retorna `True` si se cumpla la condición en particular.

Comment: Las funciones las puedes convertir a una `lambda`

Comment: estoy ejecutando el codigo,  pero no obtengo ninguna salida: porque?
`

Comment: @ANTONIOBENITEZ. La función `generar_multiples_combinaciones` parece generar una o dos combinaciones máximo. Revisa eso.

Comment: @Christian. lambda no es un reemplazo de cualquier función. Con lambda sólo puedo evaluar una expresión, con funciones puedo crear cualquier lógica.